# how to convert an existing large program to non deprecated opengl

Tags: opengl

I have a large program. I need to change it in such a way so that it uses non-deprecated features of OpenGL. I have been able to render a cylinder, sphere, etc. on a separate program, but when I attempt to incorporate the code for cylinder in the large program, I don't see expected results. I have been assuming that following code enables and disables programmable pipeline respectively:

```
glUseProgram(Program);
```

and

```
glUseProgram(0);
```

Since the program is very large, the fixed function pipeline is also in effect side by side. I believe the fixed function pipeline is interfering with my programmable pipeline. I believe this because, as I have already mentioned, I could render a cylinder separately, but, when I tried to get that code in the large program, I failed to see expected results.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Blood, sweat and tears. Other than that you do not supply enough information (code) to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good explanations here:
http://www.jeffwofford.com/?p=635
and here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/184409-Migration-from-Fixed-pipeline-to-Programmable-pipeline

The second link's comments of mhagain have helped me. I am quoting him below:

> OK, there are two steps here and I'd advise that it will go a LOT
>   easier for you if you take them one at a time rather than trying to do
>   both at the same time.
>
> First step is to move away from immediate mode to buffer objects. 
>   Second step is to move from fixed vertex and fragment processing to
>   shaders.
>
> I recommend that you take the second step first, and the reason why
>   is that having a shader infrastructure already in place can make some
>   of the decisions you'll be making about the move from immediate mode
>   to buffer objects a little easier.
>
> This isn't as daunting as it may seem on the surface. You can, for
>   example, port to a roughly GL 2.1 equivalent just converting your
>   vertex transform and lighting, and your fragment processing (i.e
>   glTexEnv calls) to shaders that do the same thing. A realistic
>   objective at this stage is to have a functionally identical program
>   that no longer uses the fixed pipeline at the end of the port. Trying
>   to add extra features at this stage is, IMO, premature.
>
> When doing this you should be able to disable all of your scene
>   drawing, then bring it back in one step at a time. I've done a few
>   similar ports before and I normally prefer to start with the 2D GUI
>   code as the drawing is relatively simple and there are only going to
>   be a small handful of shader combinations used. So disable (i.e
>   comment-out) all drawing except your 2D GUI, then write a simple
>   vertex shader that transforms position by your ortho matrix, write a
>   simple fragment shader that outputs a flat colour (white, or whatever
>   is easily visible to confirm that it worked), link them into a
>   program, glUseProgram it, and draw. Fix any problems, then add in
>   textures. Then bring in colours. Then bring in any other GUI effects
>   you might have. Nice and slow, one step at a time, and you'll get
>   there.
>
> Having completed the 2D GUI you should have a shader-loading
>   infrastructure set up, you should have a decent understanding of how
>   to activate and switch shaders, you'll know about uniforms and maybe a
>   little about attributes, you'll know how to pass data between the
>   shader stages. Then pick something else, un-comment it, and repeat.
>   You'll go a little faster this time as you'll already have much of the
>   groundwork done. Continue repeating until this first stage is
>   completed.
>
> Now you can begin porting to buffer objects. Again, it's going to be
>   easier if you don't try to jump over too many GL_VERSIONs at the same
>   time, so stick to the fixed vertex attribs (glVertexPointer,
>   glTexCoordPointer, etc) for now. Go through your drawing routines and
>   divide your vertex data into two main groups: data that doesn't change
>   from frame-to-frame and data that does. Then look at the second group
>   more closely: is it all really data that does change? E.g, you may
>   have some keyframe animation, and that can be handled in a vertex
>   shader instead of updating the data all the time; move it back to the
>   first group. You may have a particle system and again the particle
>   movement may be able to be handled by sending an unchanging position
>   but applying a simple physics equation in a vertex shader; first group
>   again. This is why I recommended doing shaders first: if you hadn't
>   then this line of approach wouldn't have been available to you.
>
> For the data that absolutely does need to change you have a few
>   options. You can just continue using immediate mode: it'll still work
>   with GL 2.1. You can convert it to client-side vertex arrays. You can
>   look at getting some buffer object streaming set up.
>
> After having completed this you should have your functionally
>   identical program that no longer uses the fixed pipeline and (possibly
>   mostly) no longer uses immediate mode. Then it's time to jump up to a
>   higher GL_VERSION, if you wish (you may decide that you're happy with
>   the result and call it mission accomplished), or you may instead
>   prefer to add some extra features (you've probably got some per-vertex
>   work that you'll get a better quality result from by moving it to
>   per-fragment; lighting is a classic example), optimize a little, or
>   whatever.